# opencv face recognition, getting measurement of similarity

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I use opencv2.4.3 to build a face recognition project. Now I just want to know how similar two faces are. Like 98% similar or something else. Forgive My poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use LBP face recognizer model and get one of the images to be saved in a Mat variable, train the model with this face. After tat get the other images and let the model predict which label it actally belongs.....the model can return confidence values as well...lesser the confidence value more wil be the accuracy...so relate the confidence value with the percentage of likliness...........